# Is it possible to partition bandwidth between access points?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, bandwidth

I am a tenant of an apartment with 7 people, and there are two other apartments in my building with 7 people (3 x 7 = 21 people), each with ~2-3 devices (laptop, phone, xbox, etc.). my landlord set up a 1 Gbps network with 3 UniFi access points, one in each apartment. There is only one SSID being broadcast, so everyone in the whole building is connected to the same network.

The problem is, my landlord has capped each device on the network to 5 Mbps to maintain "fairness" (according to them). Of course, thinking about this has lead me to the realization that we can never use the majority of the available bandwidth if all devices are throttled -- there will be a pool of bandwidth that, even though it exists, will never be available to us.

I'm working with them to figure out a new solution for our network, and I'm wondering if there's a way to "partition" the 1 Gbps bandwidth in three.

i.e. each access point would be broadcasting its own SSID, and all tenants in one apartment would connect to their apartment's access point and share a theoretical 333 Mbps connection. (I may be wrong about how this bandwidth is divided.)

I don't want to have a system where there is only one broadcasted SSID, and **I don't want to cap individual devices' bandwidth to maintain fairness on the network** -- I want the individual people in each apartment to deal with that themselves. So, if one person in Apartment A is downloading a ton of stuff and hogging all the bandwidth, then the other people in the apartment will notice (if it is a problem) and go tell them to knock it off.

I hope I've explained this properly -- if there is some other setup with this hardware that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need three SSIDs for such a solution.

Depending on the hardware involved, either the three access-paths need to be
reprogrammed for 300 Mbs (one cannot achieve the full 1 Gbs) and different
SSIDs, or if impossible someone should finance buying more evolved access path
transmitters for the landlord.

The "fairness" part will come from divulging the password for each SSID only
to the people in one apartment. Afterwards it is up to them to limit their
bandwidth consumption according to some internal agreement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that given 2017 Internet usage patterns in most countries, 1 Gbps is plenty to split between 21 people (~48 Mbps/person) or ~63 devices (~16Mbps per device). Every device could stream 1080p60 HD video 24/7 and there'd still be bandwidth to spare! That's more video streams than eyes!

I'd recommend taking off the cap completely as an experiment for a month or two and see if anyone complains about not getting at least 20Mbps to one of their devices. If not, leave the cap off. If there *are* problems, make sure they're really congestion problems on the 1Gbps link before implementing a per-device 16Mbps bandwidth cap. Typical problems to watch for, which are not congestion on the 1Gbps link, include bufferbloat, wireless airtime contention issues, wireless interference, equipment failure, etc.

I could imagine a Tor exit node or someone doing a lot of BitTorrent becoming a problem, but cross that bridge when you come to it.